# PlayFramework Configuration - Long Strings

Tags: json, scala, playframework, hocon

How can I handle very long strings in Play's application.conf? Suppose I have:

```
my.value.param = "Very very very very long line"
```

and I want to split long line like

```
my.value.param = "Very very very "
               + "very long line"
```

How can I do this using HOCON format? Thanks

Comment: Just curious what is the _content_ of these strings? ANd why do you want to split them?

Comment: Content is H2 url with long INIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#multi-line-strings) it appears to not be possible in that way. You could work around it slightly, like this:

```
my.value.param = ${my.value.param1} ${my.value.param2}
my.value.param1="Very very very"
my.value.param2="very long line"
```

But this is very ugly, of course. I don't think it was ever the intention to have long strings stored in the configuration.

Comment: It seems to allow array concatenation with `+=`. Perhaps file an issue on github for string concatenation?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be usable, I will try

Answer (score 4):

```
build.path = ${PATH}
build.path = ${build.path}":/opt/groovy-2.4.5/bin"
build.path = ${build.path}":/opt/gradle-2.9/bin"
build.path = ${build.path}":/opt/scala-2.11.7/bin"
build.path = ${build.path}":/opt/sbt-0.13.9/bin"
```